# Event Date Asc Not Right

Tags: mysql, date

how to do this right

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(EventDate, '%b %d, %Y') 
from details 
Order by STR_TO_DATE(EventDate, '%d-%m-%y')
```

sample records,

```
Oct 24, 2012
Oct 27, 2012
Oct 28, 2012
Oct 20, 2012
Dec 22, 2012
Jan 11, 2013
Jan 19, 2013
Nov 24, 2012
Dec 29, 2012
```

Comment: You treat `EventDate` as `VARCHAR` and as `DATE`. What's data type is it?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(EventDate, '%b %d, %Y') from details Order by EventDate
```

Comment: that is my query to order the date but the date is not correctly in order as you can see

Comment: @MargzJacela tom is right, what do you exactly mean bynot correctly in order? what is the data type of your column `EventDate`?

Comment: What data type is the EventDate field?  If it is a date this query will sort it correctly.

Comment: If it's not a date, what do the entries look like before being formatted?

Comment: @Margz, my query is not the same as yours.

Comment: the type is date cant you see its not correct? look carefully 

2012-10-20 |

2012-10-24 |

2012-10-27 |

2012-10-28 |

2012-11-24 |

2012-12-22 |

2012-12-29 |

2013-01-11 |

2013-01-19 |

Comment: If the EventDate field is of type Date, then removing the STR_TO_DATE function from your order by clause should fix the problem.  Like in my answer.  If you are using that STR_TO_DATE function on an actual date field, you will get NULL as a result.  That could be why your ordering is not working.

Comment: A quick way to see why your ORDER BY clause is not working, is to put the same expression in you SELECT clause.  This would make it easy to debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
Order by STR_TO_DATE(EventDate, '%d-%m-%y')
```

So we start with `EventDate` which you say is a `DATE` and we feed it as first argument to `STR_TO_DATE()`. Such function expects a string, so MySQL casts your date as string possibly using the default format (YYYY-MM-DD). Then it tries to cast the string to date using DD-MM-YYYY as format but your string is not in that format. Do you understand where I want to go?

To sum up: you don't need to cast a date to date--it's already a date!

```
Order by EventDate
```